# How to create a rose plot with lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a rose plot of chromosome data as follows

```
    structure(list(chr = c(11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 
16, 16, 18, 2, 2, 20, 20, 3, 4, 4), leftPos = c(17640000, 2880000, 
29040000, 19680000, 6120000, 6480000, 14880000, 16200000, 17760000, 
13560000, 21240000, 7080000, 10440000, 16800000, 49080000, 12240000, 
8280000, 13320000, 12000000, 13560000), Means.x = c(218.523821652113, 
256.117545073851, 343.541494875886, 348.237645885147, 426.983644179467, 
228.568161732039, 283.269605668063, 440.686146437743, 218.674798674891, 
264.556139561699, 232.068688576066, 226.877793789348, 224.282711224934, 
215.935347248385, 253.472008896076, 230.683794652539, 305.788038763088, 
285.805349707436, 644.897029710454, 485.630136931446), Def.x = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Means.y = c(236.188586172547, 
345.958953367193, 250.194040077771, 304.25175004754, 336.629006416052, 
221.495167672412, 231.719055660279, 231.252826188427, 334.254524914754, 
271.392526335334, 236.848569235568, 261.62635228236, 246.090793604293, 
370.773978424351, 242.493276055677, 245.097715487835, 280.225103337613, 
370.736474095631, 1014.42590543955, 236.718929160423), Def.y = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("chr", 
"leftPos", "Means.x", "Def.x", "Means.y", "Def.y"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Initially I was pretty pleased with myself because I could get these plots

[image]

using this code:

```
ggplot(ZoutliersM)+
  geom_point(aes(x = ZoutliersM$leftPos/1000000,y = as.numeric(ZoutliersM$Def.x)),stat="identity",fill="magenta",size=2,colour="red")+
  geom_bar(aes(x = ZoutliersM$leftPos/1000000,y = as.numeric(ZoutliersM$Def.x)),stat="identity",fill="purple",size=1,colour="red")+
  ylim(0, 1)+
  ggtitle("Shared")+
  #geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0))+
  coord_polar(theta = "x", start = 0)+
  facet_wrap(~ chr)
```

However I have a problem with using geom_bar as I constantly get the error

```
position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
```

and I think the output is incorrect as it doesn't plot all of the points.

So I spent ages searching for an answer but really didn't get much. I think it's an error related to the fact that `geom_bar` thinks that the bar widths are all different sizes and doesn't like it. I've tried changing to `stat='bin'` but I don't want a frequency plot, I want to just have a line from the point to the x-axis.

So the question is how can I do this and avoid the geom_bar all together. Is there, for example a way of having vline drawn for each point down to the `y=0` point?

**Edit**

so then I tried this

```
ggplot(ZoutliersM)+
  geom_point(aes(x = ZoutliersM$leftPos/1000000,y = as.numeric(ZoutliersM$Def.x)),stat="identity",fill="magenta",size=2,colour="red")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = ZoutliersM$leftPos/1000000, linetype= 1, colour = "#919191")+
  ylim(0, 1)+
  ggtitle("Shared")+
  #geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0))+
  coord_polar(theta = "x", start = 0)+
  facet_wrap(~ chr)
```

and I got this:

[image]

but now all the vlines are plotted on one graph and then replicated per chromosome. so not working still

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `geom_segment()`, which allows you to use two coordinates to specify a line segment: `(x,y)` and `(xend,yend)`.  The `(x,y)` coordinates are the same as your point, while the `(xend,yend)` coordinate represent the other end of the line segment.  In this case, since we want the line to extend from the point to the x-axis, `xend` should be the same as `x` and `yend` should be 0.  I've consolidated all of your `aes()` variables into one, but everything else not related to `geom_segment()` I've kept the same:

```
ggplot(ZoutliersM,aes(x = ZoutliersM$leftPos/1000000,y = as.numeric(ZoutliersM$Def.x),
                      xend=ZoutliersM$leftPos/1000000,yend=0))+
  geom_point(stat="identity",fill="magenta",size=2,colour="red")+
  geom_segment(linetype= 1, colour = "#919191")+
  ylim(0, 1)+
  ggtitle("Shared")+
  coord_polar(theta = "x", start = 0)+
  facet_wrap(~ chr)
```

[image]